# Where I can find SOTA models of information retrieval?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, reference-request, state-of-the-art, information-retrieval

Can someone tell me where I can find SOTA models of information retrieval?

My task is to rank documents by given query by semantic search of embedding. I know that models like ColBERT, SPLADE solve this problem, but I think they are not SOTA now. I tried to find SOTA models on paperswithcode but there almost nothing about this problem.